# Atom Package Manager (apm): Creating new version failed: GitHub API returned error: TooManyRequests

Tags: atom-editor, github-api

Whenever I try to publish a new version for my package, I get a TooManyRequests error:

```bash
foo$ apm publish -t v0.3.0
Publishing foo@v0.3.0 ✗
Creating new version failed: [object Object]

foo$ apm publish -t v0.3.0
Publishing foo@v0.3.0 ✗
Creating new version failed: GitHub API returned error: TooManyRequests
```

I am logged in to apm and given it permissions and I have more than enough requests available:

```
$  curl -I https://api.github.com/users/myusername
HTTP/2 200 
server: GitHub.com
date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 11:30:43 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
etag: W/"7a839c48304b16904df922608ba9dd52dec979f055370bfad9859741eb387d51"
last-modified: Wed, 21 Sep 2022 14:46:58 GMT
x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset
access-control-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
x-frame-options: deny
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 0
referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 54
x-ratelimit-reset: 1663846664
x-ratelimit-resource: core
x-ratelimit-used: 6
```

How can it be rate limited when I still have 54 of 60 available?

### Versions

```
$ apm --version
apm  2.6.5
npm  6.14.9
node 16.16.0 x64
atom unknown
python 3.10.7
git 2.37.3
```

Comment: I havn’t seen this particular error myself, but publishing new or updated packages has rarely been working in the past couple of months. Most commonly, I get status code 500. It’s a known problem that will likely never get fixed in the wake of GitHub’s [announcement to retire Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/).

Comment: @idleberg: Ok, then I will archive the package. Do you want to make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it and close the question?

Comment: Before you’re archiving the package, let me tell you that the servers for one of the community-maintained forks, [Pulsar](https://github.com/pulsar-edit/pulsar), are almost ready to take over. Will write a more thorough answer this evening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since GitHub has announced it is [sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/), publishing new or updated packages has rarely been working. [Several issues](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues?q=publish%20package) document this unfortunate behavior, though status code 500 appears to be the predominant reason.

With two community-driven forks in the making, [Pulsar Editor](https://github.com/pulsar-edit/) and [Atom Community](https://github.com/atom-community), there is some hope that you can continue to publish your packages in the future.