# Atom searching and installing packages error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

**goal:** installing jupyter-notebook plugin in atom

**problem:** errors while searching for plugins and when attempting to install (see error messages below)

**what I have tried:** installing from atom.io since the search error has been posted here before and
that was a suggestion (has not worked since that opens an atom URL and my problem is not only searching for, but also installing plugins.)

**error messages:**

*searching:*

```
i.filter is not a function
[object Object]
```

*installing:*

```
Request for package information failed: Application error
```

**other:**

atom version: 1.60.0

python: miniconda: python 3.9.12

windows build: 19044.2130

thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Atom Package Manager (apm): Creating new version failed: GitHub API returned error: TooManyRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73813926/atom-package-manager-apm-creating-new-version-failed-github-api-returned-err)